# redirect 301 with special character like WIX site "#!"

Tags: php, functions, permalinks, redirect, htaccess

i want migrate a WIX website to wordpress and i want preserve the SEO score without broken the url of every post-page. but the structure of WIX url is composed by special character like "#!" , now how i can create a 301 that work.

the structure of wix url  is like this :

```
www.wix.com/#!this-is-a-test-page/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7
```

so i want redirect to a standard wordpress url example :

```
 www.wix.com/this-is-a-test-page/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7
```

now i tried a simple redirect 301 in htacess like this:

```
redirect 301 /#!this-is-a-test-page/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7 
www.wix.com/this-is-a-test-page2/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7
```

but not work, how i can solve this ?

Comment: If you put `site:www.yourdomain.com` (substituting your domain name, obviously) into Google, do you get URLs like this in the result or do you get a different set?

Comment: @ Andy Macaulay-Brook : google are indexed the site with special character  “#!” , like this www.wix.com/#!this-is-a-test-page/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are used in web addresses to navigate to anchors on a specific position within a page. The part after the # symbol is never sent to the server. That's probably why WordPress doesn't allow hashes in URLs. If it did, you wouldn't be able to access the page anyway.